# How do a get a specific attribute from AWS Cognito user pools after user?.getDetails call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

After signing in successfully I want to get the value of a particular attribute.  Is it possible to do this without iterating through each attribute?  I know I can't subscript but is there any other way?

So in the example below what I want is the value of the user's email.  Ideally, I would like to say `let email = userAttributes["email"]` but this type does not allow subscription.

```
user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (task) -> Any? in
    let userAttributes = task.result?.userAttributes

    for attribute in userAttributes! {
        print(attribute.name!)
        print(attribute.value!)
    }
    return nil
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that `AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType` contains both a name and a value, we can easily map over that data to make a dictionary that can be accessed by a key value.

Add this extension somewhere

```
extension Array where Element: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType {
    func dict() -> [String : String] {
        var dict: [String : String] = [:]
        self.forEach({ e in dict[e.name!] = e.value! })
        return dict
    }
}
```

then use

```
task.result?.userAttributes.dict()[...]
```